# Can I show separate datatable in one php page based click on li className?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Can I show separate Datatable in one php page based click on li className.

I have these list when I click **paid** then show it **paid records** from database and when I click on **unpaid** then show it **unpaid records** from database using javascript. When **paid records** are show then one datatable show and when unpaid records show then two datatable showing.

```
<ul class="content-box-tab order_type" style="float:  right;margin: 0 !important;padding: 10px 15px 0 0 !important;">
      <li><a  sub="paid" class="paid">Paid</a></li>
      <li><a  sub="unpaid" class="unpaid">Unpaid</a></li>
      <li><a  sub="delivered" class="delivered">Delivered</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my html table

```
<!-- Paid Table -->  
   <table border="0" id="example">
  <?php 
     $limit=50;
     $delivery= $db->select(array("*"),PREFIX."order","order_status= '4' && delivery = '0' && purchase_order_no like '%SO-%' && branchId= '$employee_branch'","","updatiion_date DESC","$limit"); ?>                        
    <thead>
     <?php if(isset($_SESSION['green'])) { ?>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4"><div class="notification success png_bg"> <a href="#" class="close"><img src="resources/images/icons/cross_grey_small.png" title="Close this notification" alt="close" /></a>
            <div> <?php echo $_SESSION['green']; ?></div>
          </div></th>
      </tr>
      <?php 
                        unset($_SESSION['green']);
                        } ?>
      <?php if(isset($_SESSION['red'])) { ?>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4"><div class="notification error png_bg"> <a href="#" class="close"><img src="resources/images/icons/cross_grey_small.png" title="Close this notification" alt="close" /></a>
            <div> <?php echo $_SESSION['red']; ?></div>
          </div></th>
      </tr>
      <?php  
                        unset($_SESSION['red']);
                        } ?>
      <tr>
        <th>Order No</th>
        <th>Order Date </th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Total Price</th>
        <th>Actions </th>
      </tr>

    </thead>
 <tbody>

      <?php foreach($delivery as $del){?>
       <tr class="heightSetting">
            <td><?php echo $del->purchase_order_no?></td>
            <td><?php  echo   date('Y:m:d', strtotime($del->updatiion_date));?></td>
            <td><?php echo $del->vendor_name?></td>
            <td><?php echo $del->total_price?></td>
            <td>
            <input type="button" class="button modalLink btn" view_id="<?php echo $del->purchase_order_id;?>" value="View"
            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewModal"> 
             <?php if($del->delivery == 0){?> <input type="button" class="deliver_status button btn" id="<?php echo $del->purchase_order_id;?>" value="Delivered">  <?php }?>
            </td>
         </tr>
        <?php }?>



        </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">


          <div class="clear"></div></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>




  </table>

 <!--------------> 


<!-- Unpaid Table -->
  <table border="0" id="example1" style="display:none">
  <?php 
  $limit=50;
  $delivery= $db->select(array("*"),PREFIX."order","order_status= '3' && delivery = 0 && purchase_order_no like '%SO-%' && branchId= '$employee_branch'","","updatiion_date DESC","$limit"); ?> 

    <thead>


      <?php if(isset($_SESSION['green'])) { ?>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4"><div class="notification success png_bg"> <a href="#" class="close"><img src="resources/images/icons/cross_grey_small.png" title="Close this notification" alt="close" /></a>
            <div> <?php echo $_SESSION['green']; ?></div>
          </div></th>
      </tr>
      <?php 
                        unset($_SESSION['green']);
                        } ?>
      <?php if(isset($_SESSION['red'])) { ?>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4"><div class="notification error png_bg"> <a href="#" class="close"><img src="resources/images/icons/cross_grey_small.png" title="Close this notification" alt="close" /></a>
            <div> <?php echo $_SESSION['red']; ?></div>
          </div></th>
      </tr>
      <?php  
                        unset($_SESSION['red']);
                        } ?>
      <tr>
        <th>Order No</th>
        <th>Order Date </th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Total Price</th>
        <th>Actions </th>
      </tr>

    </thead>



      <tbody>

      <?php foreach($delivery as $del){?>
       <tr class="heightSetting">
            <td><?php echo $del->purchase_order_no?></td>
            <td><?php  echo   date('Y:m:d', strtotime($del->updatiion_date));?></td>
            <td><?php echo $del->vendor_name?></td>
            <td><?php echo $del->total_price?></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="button modalLink btn" view_id="<?php echo $del->purchase_order_id;?>" value="View"
            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewModal"> 
            <?php if($del->delivery == 0){?> <input type="button" class="deliver_status button btn" id="<?php echo $del->purchase_order_id;?>" value="Delivered">  <?php }?>
            </td>
         </tr>
        <?php }?>



        </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">


          <div class="clear"></div></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>




  </table>

 <!-------------->
```

Here is javacript code

```
$(document).on('click', '.paid', function () {
   $('#example').show();
   $('#example1').hide();
 });

$(document).on('click', '.unpaid', function () {
  $('#example').hide();
  $('#example1').show();
});
```

My datatable script

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
   "iDisplayLength": 50
});

$('#example1').DataTable( {
   "iDisplayLength": 50
});
```

Comment: Whats not working?

Comment: its working When i click unpaid li then two datatable showing I want one datatable accordingly to li click

Comment: Check you don't have multiple `example1` ids on the page.

Comment: what do you mean? I dont have multiple example?

Comment: can you explain it with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, wrap the tables in divs and hide them. You also don't need to initialise datatables on each of your tables unless the have specific/different options, instead, you can use a class:

```js
$(function() {
  // init data tables (on payment_tables class)
  var payment_tables = $('.payment_tables').DataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 50
  });
  
  // hide the unpaid table
  $('#unpaid_table').hide();

  // when paid is clicked show paid table, hide unpaid
  $('a.paid').on('click', function() {
    $('#unpaid_table').hide();
    $('#paid_table').show();
  });

  // when unpaid is clicked show unpaid table, hide paid
  $('a.unpaid').on('click', function() {
    $('#paid_table').hide();
    $('#unpaid_table').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<ul class="content-box-tab order_type" style="float:  right;margin: 0 !important;padding: 10px 15px 0 0 !important;">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" sub="paid" class="paid">Paid</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" sub="unpaid" class="unpaid">Unpaid</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" sub="delivered" class="delivered">Delivered</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="paid_table">
  <h1>Paid</h1>
  <table class="payment_tables" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A paid user</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$3,120</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="unpaid_table">
  <h1>Unpaid</h1>
  <table class="payment_tables" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A Not paid user</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$3,120</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

If you expect there may be many more tables types (awaiting, on-hold, blocked, rejected, chargeback'ed etc etc) added, then I suggest you look into making it abit more dynamic instead of hardcoding many `.hide()/.show()`'s